# Make text as UINavigationController back button

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar

I need to make this kind of navigation bar

[image]

But I don't know how can I set backBarButton as text. Should I create xib that will replace my navigation bar or I can do it programmatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In viewDidLoad set your custom button navBar:

```
let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
    //Set the image
    button.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "chevron.backward"), for: .normal)
    //Set the title
    button.setTitle("Yourtitle", for: .normal)
    //Add target
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(callMethod), for: .touchUpInside) //call button tap action
    // Add insets padding
    let spacing: CGFloat = -10 // the amount of spacing to appear between image and title
    button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: spacing, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0) // customize your button titleEdgeInsets if you want
    //Create bar button
    let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton
```

After that create your function for button tap:

```
@objc fileprivate func callMethod() {
    print("Your code here")
}
```

Comment: Upvoted, but some of the code may not be needed. Specifically the things related to images and frames. The trick - which is the pieces in your code that *is* needed - is to (1) create a UIButton that looks like what is needed as your UIBarButton and then (2) create a bar button from it using `UIBarButtonItem(customView:)` and finally (3) make it the nav bar's left bar button using `navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem`.

Comment: @dfd I add all parameters for show how to do, so you can customize it as you see fit to use it. If you take a look to  button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0), all variables are 0.... In general you're right :)